# Unable to find file path using workbooks.open in VBA

Tags: vba, macos, file, csv, import

I am new to VBA howeverI have come across a bit of a stumbling block.

I need to import a CSV file to automate some data.

using a pc I have been able to import the data fine using the below code:

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="File path is inserted here", local:=True

The above code works fine.

However, when trying this on my Mac, I get a file path error.

I managed to get round this but then returned the file or folder may be read only (which its not). Checked the file to read+write but when entering the file path again I got the same old error of not being able t find the file.

I am racking my brains here as I have tried using ":" and "\" as separators however the file path is still not found

Any help would be much appreciated.

Oh and I have also recorded a macro and imported the file manually, which bought up a whole list of code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that Macs use <kbd>/</kbd> as a path separator. `Application.PathSeparator` will give you the correct separator.

Comment: Can you not prompt for the path + file name instead of hard-coding it? I would expect `Application.GetOpenFileName` to give you a well-formed path for the platform it's running on. Hard-coding paths and file names is never a very good idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have gone with Application.GetOpenFilename()
for now which is good enough for what I need at the moment.